# How can I better handle exporting methods from services?

Tags: node.js, typescript, design-patterns, adonis.js

I am trying to figure out a better way to organize my codebase (my Services).
Right now I have a folder for my Services and a class (like AuthService.ts) and inside I have my methods (example: registerUser, loginUser).

I was plannning to do something like this:

```
// AuthService/registerUser.ts
class RegisterUser {
  public async handler (userData: UserData) {
    // code to register user
    return user
  }
}
export default new RegisterUser().handler

// ./AuthService/loginUser.ts
class LoginUser {
  public async handler (userData: UserCredentials) {
    // code to login user 
    return {user, token}
  }
}
export default new LoginUser().handler

// ./AuthService/index.ts
import loginUser from './loginUser'
import registerUser from './registerUser'
export default {loginUser, registerUser}

// Controller
import AuthService from 'App/Services/AuthService'
export default class SessionsController {
public async register ({ request }: HttpContextContract) {
    const { name, email, password } = request.post()
    const user = await AuthService.registerUser({ name, email, password })
    if (!user) {
      console.log('failed!?')
    }
    return { user }
  }
}
```

I separated all my methods in new classes. I made an `index.ts` file to make easier to export all those methods (don't break my old implementation), but I could just import the specific method I need instead of all the services.

This is write on AdonisJS v5, but the real doubt is about structure, import/export, and architecture.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? What should be the right way to better organize a Service with a lot of methods? (This is an example, actually there are 4 more methods.. and a few to come...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. `Is there anything wrong with this approach?`**

-> **No**

Except for a small problem with your method-as-class exporter.

`export default new ClassName().method` means that WHENEVER you do the `import`, the app creates a new `ClassName` instance. It's not a really big problem as I said, but please think about 2 solutions below:

- register an app `singleton` -> I don't think we need to :D
- use static methods in case you can handle things without non-static properties. Then the export should be `export default ClassName.method`

**II. `What should be the right way to better organize a Service with a lot of methods?`**

-> **I'm not sure :D** But this below is how I did. It's similar to yours.

Structure:

```
  Services
  |-- Service1
  |--|-- method1AsClass.ts
  |--|-- method2AsClass.ts
  |--|-- index.ts
```

methodXAsClass.ts

```
class methodAsClassX {
  static attr1: <type>;

  private static async helper1 () {
    // code. Eg:
    fn(MethodAsClassX.attr1) 
  }

  private static async helper1 () {
     // code
  }

  public static async invoke (param: <Param1DataType>) {
    // code
    return result
  }
}
export default methodAsClassX.invoke
```

index.ts

```
import method1 from './method1AsClass'
import method2 from './method2AsClass'

export default {method1, method2}
```

Usage:

```
import Service1 from 'App/Services/Service1'
or
import {method1} from 'App/Services/Service1'
```